# How to get result of rollup query for a custom entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

When trying to get the records I get this error

```
The 'Rollup' method does not support entities of type 'new_X'.
```

This is my code

```
RollupRequest req = new RollupRequest();
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
qe.EntityName = "new_x";
qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
req.Query = qe;
req.Target = new EntityReference("new_newpost", new Guid("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
req.RollupType = RollupType.Related;
RollupResponse resp = (RollupResponse)xrm.Execute(req);
```

How can I get the results of rollup query

Thanks in advance

---

For custom entities you can do the fallowing

```
var rollupQuery = xrm.GoalRollupQuerySet.Where(c => c.Id == x.new_RecordstoRun.Id).First();
var result = xrm.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(rollupQuery.FetchXml));
```

But - How can I add a 'Skip' or 'Take' Linq to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code so get the results of RollupQuery

```
List<Guid> GetAllResultsFromRollupQuery(XrmServiceContext xrm, Guid rollupQueryId)
{
    var rollupQuery = xrm.GoalRollupQuerySet.Where(v => v.Id == rollupQueryId).First();
    var qa = GetQueryExpression(xrm, rollupQuery.FetchXml);

    qa.PageInfo.Count = 1000;
    qa.ColumnSet.AddColumn(rollupQuery.QueryEntityType + "id");

    var result = new List<Guid>();
    EntityCollection ec = null;

    do
    {
        ec = xrm.RetrieveMultiple(qa);
        ec.Entities.ToList().ForEach(v => result.Add((Guid)v.Attributes[rollupQuery.QueryEntityType + "id"]));
        qa.PageInfo.PageNumber += 1;

    } while (ec.MoreRecords == true);


    return result;
}

QueryExpression GetQueryExpression(XrmServiceContext xrm, string fetchXml)
{
    var req = new FetchXmlToQueryExpressionRequest { FetchXml = fetchXml };
    var result = (FetchXmlToQueryExpressionResponse)xrm.Execute(req);
    return result.Query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `RollupRequest` on a certain set of entities described on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.rolluprequest.aspx).

So this will never work for "new_x" or "new_newpost".

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913608.aspx) has a correct demonstration of the `RollupRequest` using opportunity and account.

I would suggest just creating your own custom `QueryExpression` to retrieve all "new_x" and then link to "new_newpost" with `LinkEntities`.